# How do I bind context to event handler so event and a few more arguments passed to handler function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a function:

```
function clickButton(event, someArgument) {...}
```

And I need to pass it as event handler in my React component. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
onClick={clickButton.bind(this, event, someArgument)}
```

But event is not defined that is predictable.

There should be some trivial solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass additional data to an event handler in React, you can use an arrow function. This would be the most common solution, but I'll also provide you with a solution using only bind.

```
onClick={event => clickButton(event, someArgument)}
```

As you're using an arrow function, there should be no need to bind the `this` value either.

With bind, you can try something else, but you'll have to modify your handler function a bit too:

```
onClick={clickButton.bind(this, someArgument)}

function clickButton(someArgument, event) {

}
```

Personally, I think the arrow function is easier read, but [this JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/arrow-function-versus-bound-event-handlers/1) shows that a bound function is more performant, at least at the time of writing.

The results on my machine were as follows:
Opera ran bound functions 30% faster than the arrow functions. While Firefox showed no difference between the two. Strangely though, Opera did get a much higher score across the board. This likely means that Blink is currently much more optimised for ES6 than Gecko is.

Comment: doing an inline lambda function creates a new function signature for every render cycle. which makes react re-render everything every time. this is not an optimal solution

Comment: And because `someArgument` is likely an object with changing reference (otherwise it could just be a `const` member of the class), `bind` will (as far as I know) have the exact same situation, as all that binding does is returning a new function with the bound values.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Seems (at least at the time of writing) that `bind` is indeed more performant. Not sure if that's because arrow functions are still new and can benefit from more optimisation by the browser, or because it's just plain slower. But I created a JSPert to prove that using `bind` is 30% faster in Opera (again, at the time of writing).

Comment: Could you provide us a link to JSPert you created?

Comment: ^It's added to the answer :-)

Comment: @StephanBijzitter yep thats why I was recommending bind :) one thing you can do that I haven't tested in terms or performance but i'm assuming would be better / more performant is make an inline function (either lambda or bound fn) a method on your class. That way the function reference wouldn't change and would cause less re-renders. I do this for refs currently. `assignRef = target => this.container = target` and in the render `<div ref={assignRef} ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just write `onClick={clickButton.bind(this)}`, the event will be passed as argument to `clickButton`

See [React synthetic event](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

Comment: Yes, but how can I pass more arguments? Please, see function declaration in description.

Comment: For that, see @Stephan Bijzitter solution below :)

Comment: Yeah, but this was the only answer when I commented it :)